# Spring Boot properties are visible in process list (ps)

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

I have a Spring Boot process that which I run via shell, i.e

```
my-shell# java -jar my-app.jar --secret.password=text2000
```

All is good and working, but after issuing

```
ps -ef | grep "my-app" | grep -v grep
```

I can see a password and all other properties which is NOT so okay.

What can I do to not expose password like this? How to protect my password so that it would
not be possible to see it in any form via `ps -ef`?

Comment: don't expose them via system properties?

Comment: But if I will have to expose something, like a password config file location, which also
seems to be not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put those into `application.properties` (or `application.yml`) or pass them into your application process using environment variables or some similar mechanism provided by your deployment environment like [Kubernetes Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Please note that your application's security will not improve by just hiding secrets (or their location) from the process list. You should use encryption in order to protect your secrets.